# how does word2vec model cooperate with LSTM neural network

Tags: lstm, word2vec

I want to build a deep learning model for sentiment classification task on short messages' inputs. My idea is to use word2vec model in order to create a representation of words. and then use LSTM network model to classify between positive or negative.
I find it difficult to understand a few things:

1. word2vec model actually represents a neural network in itself?
   all I know it can be used for pre-training tasks but how this model output help to classification task?

2.what is the number of features I need to choose? I know that the number of features selected represents the number of neuronal units in the hidden layer.  how do I incorporate this into network learning about positive or negative emotions?

3.The idea I thought of, was to make a separate model of Word2vec for representation of words by noun attributes, adjectives etc ... and then insert the matrix weights into the LSTM network.

How is such a thing done? And how can I eventually get a probability-vector indicates a negative or positive message?

Answer (score 0):

1. Word2vec, or word embeddings, as they're usually called, can also function as a layer as part of a larger network. This is what you'd do here.
2. As a starting point for experimentation, [this PyTorch tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html) uses a hidden size of 256.
3. I'm not sure what you mean here. Normally, you'd train only one embedding.

Basically you'd just take the LSTM's hidden state after seeing the last word of the sentence and classify sentences with a dense layer taking this hidden state as input. Also see [this tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) for how to use LSTM for classification, although there is no embedding layer here (the previous link does have one).

Comment: when you say "one embedding" what do you mean?